# Interface for Array of array of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have a dataset

```
"series": [{
    "name": "Events",
    "data": [
        [0,0],
        [0,1],
        [2,2],
        ...
    ]
}]
```

What's the proper Typescript interface for this? This is not quite right:

```
export interface MyInterface {
    series: {
        name: string;
        data: number[]
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried data: number[][] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `data` is always two number elements, you should use a tuple type: `[number, number]`.

```
interface MyType {
    series: {
        name: string;
        data: [number, number][]
    }[]
};
```

If not, you should use a 2 dimensional array: `number[][]`.

```
interface MyType {
    series: {
        name: string;
        data: number[][]
    }[]
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep my typings as a single level/hierarchy, if it requires another level to describe the object, I like to create its own interface/type for that object.

Example:

```
export interface SeriesEvent {
    [0]: number,
    [1]: number
}

export interface Series {
    data: SeriesEvent[]
    name: "Events";
}

export interface MyInterface {
    series: Series
}
```